# How can I refresh a stored and snapshotted jquery selector variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, dom, jquery-selectors

I ran yesterday in a problem with a jquery-selector I assigned to a variable and it's driving me mad.

Here is a jsfiddle with testcase:

- assign the .elem to my obj var
- log both lengths to the console. Result => 4
- Remove #3 from the DOM
- log obj to the console => the removed #3 is still there and the length is still 4.
  I figured out that jquery query is snapshotted? to the variable and can't?won't? be updated
- log .elem to the console.. yep Result => 3 and the #3 is gone
- Now I update .elem with a new width of 300
- logging obj & obj.width gives me 300.. So the snapshot has been updated ? What's interesting is that 3 of the 4 divs have the new width, but the removed #3 doesn't...

Another test: Adding a li element to the domtree and logging obj and .elem. 
.elem does have the new li and obj doesn't, because it's still the old snapshot

http://jsfiddle.net/CBDUK/1/

Is there no way to update this obj with the new content? 
I don't want to make a new obj, because in my application there is a lot information saved in that object, I don't want to destroy...

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Yeah, it's a snapshot. Furthermore, removing an element from the page DOM tree isn't magically going to vanish all references to the element.

You can refresh it like so:

```
var a = $(".elem");

a = $(a.selector);
```

Mini-plugin:

```
$.fn.refresh = function() {
    return $(this.selector);
};

var a = $(".elem");

a = a.refresh();
```

This simple solution doesn't work with complex traversals though. You are going to have to make a parser for the `.selector` property to refresh the snapshot for those.

The format is like:

```
$("body").find("div").next(".sibling").prevAll().siblings().selector
//"body div.next(.sibling).prevAll().siblings()"
```

In-place mini-plugin:

```
$.fn.refresh = function() {
    var elems = $(this.selector);
    this.splice(0, this.length);
    this.push.apply( this, elems );
    return this;
};

var a = $(".elem");
a.refresh() //No assignment necessary
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and explanation! It worked very well with the .selector call. It's a jquery internal method? couldn't find any documentation for that call. Anyway.. I changed my code a little bit and made a new setter for that count and call it with setCount ($...length) which works also quite good.

Comment: @Ralk the `.selector` property is technically internal yeah.

Comment: @Esailija - Doesn't work here: http://jsfiddle.net/nJeqf/ (The .selector property was deprecated in jQuery 1.7). http://api.jquery.com/selector/

Comment: @TravisJ it doesn't work for that kind of stuff pre 1.7 either as is mentioned in the answer. The simple selector case still works as advertized in 1.9.1: http://jsfiddle.net/nJeqf/1/

Comment: @Esailija - Okay, I had interpreted the last part of your answer as being able to handle the more advanced scenarios but I guess that isn't the case.

Comment: @TravisJ yea the last part just does the refreshing in-place

Comment: [`.selector`](https://api.jquery.com/selector/) is marked as deprecated and will be removed in version 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

I also liked @Esailija solution, but seems that this.selector has some bugs with filter.
So I modified to my needs, maybe it will be useful to someone

> This was for jQuery 1.7.2 didn`t test refresh on filtered snapshots on higher versions

```
$.fn.refresh = function() { // refresh seletor
    var m = this.selector.match(/\.filter\([.\S+\d?(\,\s2)]*\)/); // catch filter string
    var elems = null;
    if (m != null) { // if no filter, then do the evarage workflow
        var filter = m[0].match(/\([.\S+\d?(\,\s2)]*\)/)[0].replace(/[\(\)']+/g,'');
        this.selector = this.selector.replace(m[0],''); // remove filter from selector
        elems = $(this.selector).filter(filter); // enable filter for it
    } else {
        elems = $(this.selector);
    }
    this.splice(0, this.length);
    this.push.apply( this, elems );
    return this;
};
```

Code is not so beautiful, but it worked for my filtered selectors.

Comment: Using regular expressions for this is not very flexible and not a good idea in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

**Clean and generic solution worked properly with jQuery 3.4.1:**

My solution is to do the following:

1. Intercept the selector at the time of jQuery object initialization and in the same time maintain all other jQuery functionalities transparently all this using inheritance
2. Build refresh plugin that make use of the new "*selector*" property we added during initialization

**Definition:**

```
$ = (function (originalJQuery) 
{
    return (function () 
    {
        var newJQuery = originalJQuery.apply(this, arguments);
        newJQuery.selector = arguments.length > 0 ? arguments[0] : null;
        return newJQuery;
    });
})($);

$.fn = $.prototype = jQuery.fn;

$.fn.refresh = function () 
{
    if (this.selector != null && (typeof this.selector === 'string' || this.selector instanceof String))
    {
        var elems = $(this.selector);
        this.splice(0, this.length);
        this.push.apply(this, elems);
    }
    return this;
};
```

**Usage:**

```
var myAnchors = $('p > a');
//Manipulate your DOM and make changes to be captured by the refresh plugin....
myAnchors.refresh();
//Now, myAnchors variable will hold a fresh snapshot
```

**Note:**
As optimization, object selectors don't need refresh as they are pass by reference by nature so, in refresh plugin, we only refresh if the selector is a string selector not object selector for clarification, consider the following code:

```
// Define a plain object
var foo = { foo: "bar", hello: "world" };
 
// Pass it to the jQuery function
var $foo = $( foo );
 
// Test accessing property values
var test1 = $foo.prop( "foo" ); // bar

// Change the original object
foo.foo = "koko";

// Test updated property value
var test2 = $foo.prop( "foo" ); // koko
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery .selector is deprecated, it's better to remeber string with selector value to some variable at the moment when you assign

```
function someModule($selector, selectorText) {
   var $moduleSelector = $selector;
   var moduleSelectorText = selectorText;

   var onSelectorRefresh = function() {
      $moduleSelector = $(moduleSelectorText);
   }
}
```

https://api.jquery.com/selector/

Answer (score 0):

You can also return the JQuery selector in a function, and save this function into the variable. Your code will look a bit different but it works. Every time when you execute the function, your jquery selector will search the DOM again.

In this example I used an arrow function without brackets which will **return** whatever is next to arrow. In this case it will return the JQuery collection.

```js
const $mySelector = () => $('.selector');
console.log($mySelector().last().text());
$('.parent').append('<li class="selector">4</li>')

console.log($mySelector().last().text()); //RETURNS 4 not 3
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="parent">
    <li class="selector">1</li>
    <li class="selector">2</li>
    <li class="selector">3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use `remove()` it will remove only a part of the DOM but not all the children or related, instead if you use `empty()` on the element the problem is gone.

E.G.:

```
 $('#parent .child).find('#foo').empty();
```

Maybe it can be useful to someone!