# Are jQuery selectors snapshots or are they updated in real time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a variable y that is derived from a jQuery selector:

```
function g() {
    jQuery('.MyProperty').each(function(){
        var x = jQuery(this);
        f(x);
    });
}

function f(x) {
    var y = x.siblings('SomeProperty').children('SomeClass');
    var myValue = random();
    y.MyValue = myValue;
    jQuery.ajax(
        /* ... */
        success: function {
            if (myValue != y.MyValue) {
                /// Do something!
            } else {
                /// Do something else!
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Now, let's suppose g() is an event handler that runs whenever user clicks a button. This means it can fire in succession. Since f() fires an asynchronous AJAX call, the browser will not block until it succeeds and that they may all arrive in some random sequence after the all the f() calls are done (remember, they don't block on the AJAX calls and will just complete), for instance:

The issue I am facing is that the y in each AJAX call back appears to be snapshots of the actual DOM object because the state of y.MyValue does not appear to change despite perturbations from calls to g() (and f() by extension) that occurred just before the call back function is run.

I wonder if there are any ways to refresh the jQuery selectors so that the state of y can get properly updated.

Edit: To clarify my concern, this is an example event queue:

```
g() /// Sets y.MyValue to 1.5555
g() /// Sets y.MyValue to 634.34
g() /// Sets y.MyValue to 555555
AJAX call back // Reads y.MyValue as 1.5555 when it should be 555555
AJAX call back // Reads y.MyValue as 555555 which is correct
g() /// Sets y.MyValue to 4232
AJAX call back // Reads y.MyValue as 4232 which is correct
AJAX call back // Reads y.MyValue as 634.34 when it should be 634.34
```

This can hypothetically occur when there there are fluctuations to response times in the server.

Comment: As Pointy said, they're snapshots. But the code in your question doesn't seem to have anything to do with that.

Comment: `y` is a local variable containing object that you created within the same scope. It is __not__ a reference to DOM, though it contains references to DOM inside. So it is not surprising that `/// Do something!` would never execute. It would be useful to understand what is the actual end goal you trying to achieve. Do you simply want to throttle AJAX requests?

Comment: Basically, I want resynch y with the appropriate DOM object. I've seen [threads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868899/how-can-i-refresh-a-stored-and-snapshotted-jquery-selector-variable) that talk about refreshing jQuery selectors, but that only works for very simple ones and not the ones that are several layers deep like y in this particular example.

Comment: This might help you understand a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/x8VFM/1/. You will notice the variable y is always the current value. You might have other issues.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery objects are NOT snapshots of the DOM.
They are just wrappers, they are objects containing references to DOM elements (that match your selector).
The fact is every time you use the jQuery function, you create a NEW instance of a jQuery object. So your g() functions passes a new instance to f() everytime. Then f creates a MyValue property on this newly created jQuery object instance. Then you create a New success handler for every ajax call.
y.MyValue and myValue will always be equal because you create new instances of everything everytime and tell this values to be equal.

Comment: Okay, can you guys please sort out that snapshot versus not snapshot argument.

Comment: jQuery objects are wrappers, they contain indexed (like an array) references to elements.
If no match is found for the selector you passed to the jQuery function or if you pass no argument at all to the jQuery function, a jQuery object is still returned, only with an empty set of elements.

Try for yourself : `console.log(jQuery('a'))` will return you an object containing references to all the links in the page, indexed from 0 to number of links - 1.

Then of course, jQuery objects provide methods to interact with the elements in the set, otherwise it could as well be an array.

Comment: When you do this : `jQuery('.MyProperty')` in your g() function, you create a new instance of jQuery object each time g() is called.
All these instances of jQuery object have the same elements in their respective set, but they are distinct instances of jQuery Object.

Comment: Same thing goes here : `var x = jQuery(this);` and here : `var y = x.siblings('SomeProperty').children('SomeClass');`. Each time your functions are called they create new instances of jQuery object. So when you do : `y.MyValue = myValue` you create a property on a newly created object. jQuery objects are not DOM.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, they are snapshots for a particular point in time. Unless I'm missing something, why not update `y` from within the success callback (using whatever selector(s) you need)?