# How to re-evaluate or refresh jquery selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a selector stored in a variable. The content in the page changes dynamically, the problem I'm facing was when the content was removed then the cached selector didn't work. How can I re-evaluate or refresh the selector?
https://jsfiddle.net/qehdvedd/

```
var selector;
function Remove(){  
selector.refresh();
  selector.remove();
}

function Add(){
    $("#div1").append('<div class="div2">New content</div>');
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    selector = $(".div2");
});

$.fn.refresh = function() {
    return $(this.selector);
};
```

I also referenced ([How can I refresh a stored and snapshotted jquery selector variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868899/how-can-i-refresh-a-stored-and-snapshotted-jquery-selector-variable)) but it does not work.
I'm aware of the alternative solutions like storing the selector name as a string and calling it with jquery.

**Edit**:
I will tell the exact scenario. I'm working on a spa website, in that if I clicked an element and go to next page in the spa. Then if I pressed Esc or back button I need to focus the last selected item also need to add a class to show which is selected. I will store the selector in a variable to know the last selected item when the element is clicked. And if the Esc key is pressed then I will focus on the variable which stored the last selected item. But due to spa the contents are removed and added dynamically. So this solution doesn't seem to work. I can't use the alternative solutions like storing the selector name as a string and calling it with jquery. Because there are too many items present on the page, so adding every item with Id is not practical.
Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/2v78hmb5/

Comment: as well as setting `selector = $(".div2");`, you should add it to your add function (after you have done your append).

Comment: Traditionally this is solved by adding/removing a CSS class to all "selected" elements and then query $(".selected") every time you need it, instead of storing a jQuery selection into a variable and letting it become stale over time. From your description I can't see why that would not be a possibility.

Comment: @Tomalak It is not possible in spa pages, because if I added a specific class to the selected elements then I go to the next page and return back to the previous page. The entire content is rebuilt every time I navigate to a page. So the class added to the selected elements will be lost when I navigate to a section. Sample spa fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2v78hmb5/

Comment: @Rebornx I see, thanks for the example. I think we can find a much better solution than storing jQuery results in global variables here. I'll get back to you.

Comment: @Rebornx This is the solution you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/2v78hmb5/5/

Comment: The whole thing will benefit from the use of the mapping plugin. Especially the `key` function, see the associated documentation under [Advanced usage](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html#advanced-usage). This will enable you to re-load a folder from the server while only updating the rows that are actually modified in the UI, instead of re-rendering the entire table.

Comment: I've made too many changes to your original source to sum up in a few sentences. Key points: **A)** Use viewmodels to keep state. Your approach was missing a "Folder" viewmodel (most probably you'll need a "Mail" viewmodel further down the road, too). **B)** Strictly avoid all jQuery code in your viewmodels. All view interaction happens through bindings. If you must use jQuery, encapsulate it in a custom binding. **C)** Work with promises in your Ajax code. It allows you to separate application logic from plumbing, helps avoid duplication, makes your code more modular and more testable.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

Unfortunately, the reason you can't use the solution from [How can I refresh a stored and snapshotted jquery selector variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11868899/1366033) is not because you've implemented anything incorrectly, but just because the solution is deprecated.

The former solution relies on the internal [`.selector`](https://api.jquery.com/selector/) property which was deprecated in v1.7 and removed in v3.0

> **Note**: This API has been removed in jQuery 3.0. The property was never a reliable indicator of the selector that could be used to obtain the set of elements currently contained in the jQuery set where it was a property, since subsequent traversal methods may have changed the set.

### Solution

I think the simplest solution is just redo the selector query from scratch.  No real performance difference between that and "refreshing" the query which will have to do the same thing anyway.  You'll end up with a *little* duplicate code, but most of the other solutions require much more indirection and complexity.

So instead of relying on a shared variable in multiple places like this:

```js
var selector = $(".div2");

function Remove() {
  selector.refresh();
  selector.remove();
}

function Add() {  
  selector.refresh();
  selector.append($main);
}
```

Instead, use inline like this:

```js
function Remove() {
  $(".div2").remove();
}

function Add() {  
  $(".div2").append($main);
}
```