# refresh jquery selector after xhr request

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have defined my elements like this on page load:

```
let cycleContainer = $('.start-cycling'),
participantActiveButton = $('#participant-is-here');
```

Both these elements do not exist at the time I load the page.
I load these elements using an XHR request with jQuery.
So how can I 'refresh' the element list after the XHR has been processed?

Without giving a the variables a new value. Something like a `cycleContainer.refresh()` method would be nice.

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868899/how-can-i-refresh-a-stored-and-snapshotted-jquery-selector-variable) topic where this is mentioned as a solution:

```
$.fn.refresh = function() {
    return $(this.selector);
};
```

But the `this.selector` isn't returning anything in my chrome browser.

Comment: Why aren't you defining the element variables in the request callback? Obviously they're not useful beforehand. Maybe show more of your script for better suggestions.

Comment: This pattern makes little intuitive sense. Why cache elements that don't exist and thus aren't cachable? It would be far more sensible to grab the elements after your XHR has resolved. If you must do it this way, store not jQ references but strings of selectors, then process them (e.g. as an array) once the XHR has finished.

Comment: Why don't you add deceleration lines after xhr...? Means where you are calling refresh function...

Comment: .selector doesnt exist anymore... http://api.jquery.com/selector/

Comment: Also use delegation if you need to add event handlers: `$("#someContainer").on("someEvent",".start-cycling",function() {....});`

Comment: Because my JS is in different files. To maintain readability I was hoping to be able to define the selectors at the top of the page and sort of reload/ refresh them afterwards.

Comment: The selectors have to be defined after the object exists - for example as global vars followed by assignments in a `$(function() {...})` page load handler