# Chosen plugin - remove "x" button (remove option) for specific options after .trigger("chosen:updated")

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-chosen

Using: jQuery 3.5.1

Basically I have multiple DDLists, rendered by server(ASP MVC app) with `selected=true` or `false` options, that I attach chosen to them, the `selected` options (that are rendered by server) should not be removed so I removed "x" button from them.
What I want now is this:

- When I choose an option from one of these DDLs, I want that option to not be available for rest of DDLs, and if I remove it -> to be available again for all DDLs -> this I already managed to get  to work (with the code below) by using `.trigger("chosen:updated")`
- Doing `.trigger("chosen:updated")`, updates all my DDLs, which implicit add "x" button to all selected options
- Now what I need is a way of prevent adding "x" button to those options that were initially rendered by server -> I've tried to save them in `search_choices` but at that moment they doesn't contain "x" button and after `.trigger("chosen:updated")`, DOM is changed and `search_choices` contains an old version of those elements.

There was a solution that is deprecated now by using [".selector"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11868946/5393271) -> which gives you a updated version of DOM elements

How can I overcome this issue? Thanks in advance!

```
   var search_choices = $("#MyFieldset").find(".search-choice");

   $("#step_5").on("change", ".ChosenDDLs", function (ev, crtSelectedOptionVal) {
    
    var all_ChosenDDLs = $(".ChosenDDLs");

    if (crtSelectedOptionVal.deselected) {
        all_ChosenDDLs .not(this).each(function (index, elem) {
            $(elem).children("option[value=" + crtSelectedOptionVal.deselected + "]")
                   .prop("disabled", false)
                   .trigger("chosen:updated");
        });
    }
    else if (crtSelectedOptionVal.selected) {
        all_ChosenDDLs .not(this).each(function (index, elem) {
            $(elem).children("option[value=" + crtSelectedOptionVal.selected + "]")
                   .prop("disabled", true)
                   .trigger("chosen:updated");
        });
    }

///search_choices here does not contain updated DOM elemets, so code below doesn't work
    if (search_choices.length > 0) {
        search_choices.each(function (index, elem) {
            $(this).find(".search-choice-close").remove();
        });
    }        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So what I actually did was to render those options as disabled (from server), so no "x" button was attached to them, and also force jQuery validation to not ignore disabled options: `:disabled:not(option)`

```
$("#form").data("validator").settings.ignore = ":disabled:not(option)";
```

Also with chosen you need to not ignore hidden `select`, so validation can work (after reparsing Validation: `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($("#form"))` )

```
$("#form").data("validator").settings.ignore = ":hidden:not(" + selectClassnameToIgnore +")";
```